# Create an off diagonal / moving window matrix

Tags: r, matrix

How to create an off diagonal / moving window matrix with R?

```
> offdiag(3, 4, 6)

1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: It's not clear about "moving window matrix". Could you give more explanations or examples?

Comment: @DarrenTsai It's perfectly clear to me. Each row corresponds to a time step and shows the position of the window.

Comment: @OP: You should consider carefully if you actually need this matrix. You don't say what you need it for but there might be better approaches (e.g., I'm a huge fan of `stats::filter`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest creating a sparse logical matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
X <- bandSparse(n = 4, m = 6, k = seq_len(3) - 1L)
X
#4 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
#
#[1,] | | | . . .
#[2,] . | | | . .
#[3,] . . | | | .
#[4,] . . . | | |
```

If you need a dense integer matrix:

```
+as.matrix(X)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily customize a function as follows:

```r
offdiag <- function(x, nrow, ncol) {
  mat <- diag(1, nrow, ncol)
  ind <- col(mat) - row(mat)
  mat[ind > 0 & ind < x] <- 1
  mat
}

offdiag(3, 4, 6)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
l <- lapply(0:3, function(x) {1:3 + x})
t(sapply(l, FUN = function(x) tabulate(x, 6)))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
#> [2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
f <- function(m, n, k) {
  mat <- matrix(nrow = m, ncol = n)
  +(abs(col(mat) - row(mat) - (k - 1) / 2) <= (k - 1) / 2)
}
```

such that for exmaple

```
> f(4, 6, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1

> f(3, 6, 4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility, using `collapse::flag`, which performs fast lags and leads:

```r
offdiag <- function(m, n, k){
   fv = c(rep(1, k), rep(0, n - k))
   t(collapse::flag(fv, n = 0:(m-1), fill = 0, stubs = FALSE))
}

offdiag(4, 6, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1

offdiag(3, 6, 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    1    1    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
```

---

**Benchmark**

On a larger matrix of 300x600, this answer is the fastest:

```r
microbenchmark(
   collapse = offdiag(3e2, 6e2, 4e2),
   TiC = f(3e2, 6e2, 4e2),
   Darren = offdiag_Darren(4e2, 3e2, 6e2)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
#  collapse 1.0943 1.2596 1.808522 1.33160 1.5143 12.2422   100
#       TiC 2.7508 3.0763 3.732139 3.26690 3.6004 13.3794   100
#    Darren 5.2730 5.6695 6.993973 5.89465 6.3810 16.7442   100
```